# The comment field is required

Tags: html, laravel

I'm trying to make a comment form but I get an error on submit that the Comment field is required, even though its filled in.

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="comment">Komentar:</label>
<textarea id="comment" class="form-control" name="comment" rows="4" cols="50" >
</textarea>
</div>
```

**CommentController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $request->validate([
         'name'=>'required' ,
         'lastname'=>'required' ,
         'email'=>'required' ,
         'tel'=>'required' ,
         'comment'=>'required', 
       ]);
```

Comment: you can check your data with $request->all()

Comment: @IV10 check `$request` before validation if it have value you have entered. try using `dd($request->all())`

Comment: dd($request->all()) , it shows all values. Is something wrong with my table ? SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'comment' doesn't have a default value.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add it to your `$fillable` array as per the answer from [omar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919486/281278).

Answer (score 2):

Just add comment to $fillable variable in your Comment Model

```
$fillable = ['other_fillable_fields...','comment'];
```

Comment: An alternative to this is to add `protected $guarded = []` instead of `protected $fillable = [...]`.

Comment: that's not a good practice to allow mass assignment.
 larave did that for a reason :'D

Comment: If you have a lot of fields but only a few don't allow mass assignment, it is a valid option.

Comment: the valid option is you add those which don't allow mass assignment to the guarded variable, not just leave it empty

Comment: Which is what I just said.  [: